# android edit-text input limit 2048 characters but I need to input 5000 characters

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-method, android-textinputedittext, android-inputtype

Android `EditText` input limit 2048 characters.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/user_input"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Here `EditText` produce a input field. Where user can input 2048 characters but I need to input more then 5000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using this function:

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.user_input);

public void setCharacterLimit(int limit){
     editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(limit)});
}
```

Comment: EditText (android.content.Context) in EditText cannot be applied to (int).
showing this error.

Comment: `android:maxLength` in xml do the same.

Comment: @grabarz121 yeap it is the same but he wants 2048 and 5000 characters separate times.